# How to deal with the first categorical column when do PCA analysis in r?

Tags: r, categorical-data, pca

I'm trying to do a PCA analysis with a dataset like:

```
food         var1   var2   var3    var4 ...  var31  var32
foodtype1    0.0012 0.8820 0.7926 0.2633 ... 0.3215 0.5233
foodtype2    0.0012 0.8820 0.7926 0.2633 ... 0.3215 0.5233
foodtype3    0.0012 0.8820 0.7926 0.2633 ... 0.3215 0.5233
```

I followed the site [PCA analysis with package "FactoMineR"](http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/factominer-and-factoextra-principal-component-analysis-visualization-r-software-and-data-mining), the example inside also has categorical column.[image] The last column was removed during PCA analysis, but used for grouping plots later, while the first column was kept. 
***I noticed that the first column without column name***.
However, when I did PCA by my data, the error showed:

```
Error in PCA(Comp_fa2, scale.unit = T, graph = T) : 
The following variables are not quantitative:  X
```

My question is, how should deal with my own data with the first non-numeric column when doing PCA analysis? 
Thank you very much.

Comment: You could convert it it into $n-1$ columns of dummy variables where $n$ is the number of categories. I would guess R has a built in function for this. For example try this method https://stackoverflow.com/a/5048727/1011724

Comment: @Dan, thank you very much for your kind suggestion, I'm working on it.

Comment: I find this answer.
[transfer the first column as row names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5555408/convert-the-values-in-a-column-into-row-names-in-an-existing-data-frame-in-r)